# Is a decision made before the rationalization?

Tags: consciousness, truth, rationality, decision-theory

Well, I was listening to a podcast in Spanish and a great scientist was saying that there are studies that are seeing that decision making is not as rational as we think it is. He says that the moment you make a decision is prior to the moment you rationalize the decision. So, we are permanently justifying decisions that we have already made.

I would like to know more about this so it would be helpful if someone could tell me the veracity of the above, what advances have been made in this field and recommendations of articles or books. I would also like to gain knowledge about the neurological point of view of consciousness and what is known about it so far.

Comment: Your first section is correct. The basic experiment and seminal paper are due to Libet, B. (1999). Do we have free will? Journal of Consciousness Studies, 6, 47-57. The Libet-experiment triggers a long discussion on the role of unconscious brain processes for human decision making.

Comment: This seems like an empirical question and not a philosophical question. The philosophical implications, however, are numerous. If you could rephrase your question to ask about specific philosophical implications (many of which have already been written about) that'd be helpful.

Comment: Is the scientist Antonio Damasio ?